# Screenshot of a panel with opened comboboxes

Tags: java, swing, popup, screenshot, jcombobox

I have a `JPanel` which includes a `JComboBox`. I am trying to take a screenshot of this panel when `JComboBox` is open. But I couldn't do it. Any idea?

If you run this code then press <kbd>Alt-P</kbd> when combo is open, you will see the problem.

```
public class ScreenShotDemo {
    /**
     * @param args
     */
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        final JPanel JMainPanel = new JPanel(new BorderLayout());

        JPanel jp = new JPanel();
        jp.add(new JComboBox<String>(new String[] { "Item1", "Item2", "Item3" }));

        final JPanel jImage = new JPanel();

        JMainPanel.add(jp, BorderLayout.WEST);
        JMainPanel.add(jImage, BorderLayout.CENTER);

        jp.getInputMap(JComponent.WHEN_IN_FOCUSED_WINDOW).put(KeyStroke.getKeyStroke(KeyEvent.VK_P, InputEvent.ALT_DOWN_MASK), "screenshot");
        jp.getActionMap().put("screenshot", new AbstractAction() {

            @Override
            public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent arg0) {
                BufferedImage bf = new BufferedImage(400, 400, BufferedImage.TYPE_INT_RGB);
                JMainPanel.paint(bf.getGraphics());
                jImage.getGraphics().drawImage(bf, 0,0,jImage);
            }
        });

        final JFrame jf = new JFrame();
        jf.getContentPane().add(JMainPanel);
        jf.setSize(500, 500);
        jf.setVisible(true);
    }
}
```

Comment: yes it is a problem i have spent hours, an important question.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The dropdown popup window is not part of the JComboBox's component hierarchy, and therefore is not drawn as part of it, but independently.

A solution to this is to take an actual screen shot using `java.awt.Robot`:

```
@Override
public void actionPerformed (ActionEvent arg0) {

    Point p = new Point(0, 0);
    SwingUtilities.convertPointToScreen(p, JMainPanel);
    Rectangle screenBounds = new Rectangle(p.x, p.y, JMainPanel.getSize().width, JMainPanel.getSize().height);

    try {
        Robot robot = new Robot();
        BufferedImage screenCapture = robot.createScreenCapture(screenBounds);

        jImage.getGraphics().drawImage(screenCapture, 0, 0, jImage);
    } catch (AWTException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
}
```

Answer (score 2):

- all `Popup`s in AWT/Swing are `Heavyweight` by default (any changes to already visible popup must be pack()'ed)
- here isn't required to use `awt.Robot` for screenshot, have to get top heavyweight component in hierarchy for heavy `BasicsComboBoxPopup`, this is `RootPane` from `JFrame`

e.g.

[image]

.

[image]

from code

```
import java.awt.BorderLayout;
import java.awt.event.ActionEvent;
import java.awt.event.InputEvent;
import java.awt.event.KeyEvent;
import java.awt.image.BufferedImage;
import javax.swing.AbstractAction;
import javax.swing.JComboBox;
import javax.swing.JComponent;
import javax.swing.JFrame;
import javax.swing.JPanel;
import javax.swing.KeyStroke;

public class ScreenShotDemo {

    private JPanel JMainPanel = new JPanel(new BorderLayout());
    private JPanel jp = new JPanel();
    private JComboBox combo = new JComboBox(new String[]{"Item1", "Item2", "Item3"});
    private JPanel jImage = new JPanel();
    private JFrame jf = new JFrame();

    public ScreenShotDemo() {
        jp.add(combo);
        JMainPanel.add(jp, BorderLayout.WEST);
        JMainPanel.add(jImage, BorderLayout.CENTER);
        jp.getInputMap(JComponent.WHEN_IN_FOCUSED_WINDOW).put(
                KeyStroke.getKeyStroke(KeyEvent.VK_P, InputEvent.ALT_DOWN_MASK), "screenshot");
        jp.getActionMap().put("screenshot", new AbstractAction() {
            @Override
            public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent arg0) {
                final BufferedImage bf = new BufferedImage(400, 400, BufferedImage.TYPE_INT_RGB);
                javax.swing.SwingUtilities.invokeLater(new Runnable() {
                    @Override
                    public void run() {
                        jf.getRootPane().paint(bf.getGraphics());
                        jImage.getGraphics().drawImage(bf, 0, 0, jImage);
                    }
                });
            }
        });
        jf.getContentPane().add(JMainPanel);
        jf.setSize(500, 500);
        jf.setVisible(true);
    }

    public static void main(String args[]) {
        javax.swing.SwingUtilities.invokeLater(new Runnable() {
            @Override
            public void run() {
                new ScreenShotDemo();
            }
        });
    }
}
```